# Как удалить нужный элемент с вложенного массива?

Tags: reactjs, filter, setstate

Помогите пожалуйста. Есть обьект data. Не получатся удалить нужный tag.

```
const data = {
  notes: [
    {
      id: v1(),
      title: 'Car',
      tags: [
        {id: v1(), title: '#cars'},
        {id: v1(), title: '#carsofinstagram'},
      ],
    },
    {
      id: v1(),
      title: 'soccer',
      tags: [
        {id: v1(), title: '#football'},
        {id: v1(), title: '#sport'},
        {id: v1(), title: '#soccer'},
      ],
    },
    {
      id: v1(),
      title: 'gaming',
      tags: [
        {id: v1(), title: '#gamer'},
        {id: v1(), title: '#playstation'},
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

```
const handleRemoveTagClick = (tagId: string, tags: TagsType): void => {
    setNotes(
      notes.map(note => {
        return {
          ...note,
          tags: tags.filter(tag => tag.id !== tagId),
        }
      }),
    )
  }
```

Comment: `id: v1()` - это вы назначаете случайный ID? Какие значения лежат в notes?

Comment: да. id title и массив с tags

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleRemoveTagClick = (tags: TagsType, tagId: string): void => {
    setNotes(
      notes.map(note => ({
        ...note,
        tags: note.tags.filter(tag => tag.id !== tagId),
      })),
    )
  }
```

использовал не тот массив(
надо было note.tags а я использовал tags из аргументов ф-ии

Comment: Примите ваш ответ, что бы вопрос был закрыт )

Comment: Через 2 дня пишет